# deploy fail Error: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My application has no error, but when I try to debug the application then deploy fail with no error and give me this output:

> :Deployment failed
>   1>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   1>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   1>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__99.MoveNext()
>   1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__98.MoveNext()
>   1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
>   1>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
>   1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>   1>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
>   1>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>   1>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__99.MoveNext()
>   1>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   1>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   1>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__98.MoveNext()<---
>   1>
>   1>Build FAILED.`

I have no idea why I am getting this and how can I remove this error. I am new in `xamarin.android` there for don't know what exactly I have to do. I try to take help from google but, I am not able to get it. Can one help me as I am stuck here from past few days.

Answer (score 10):

`INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE` happens when you already have a debug version on your phone and try to overwrite release version, or vice versa. Also it may happen when you have major changes in your new build.

Go to settings and app management. You will find your app with a **package name**, uninstall it and then try deploying again.

It should fix the issue.

Comment: You may also need to uninstall the app via command line:
adb uninstall com.mydomain.myapp

Answer (score 4):

This issue can also occur if there are security controls preventing installation. The most common might be `Play Protect` which is a feature within Google Play that attempts to block unauthorized apps. I had to turn this off in order to re-load my application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If install via USB is disabled, enable it and check again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are in **debug** mode. In Visual Studio, right-click on your project under the Solution Explorer and select Properties. 
Under the **Android Options** page , Click the **Advanced** button and under **Supported architectures** , check the architectures that you want to support:
**armeabi** for emulator , 
**x86** for mobile
(you can check both)